# TensorFlow 2.1.0: has no attribute 'random_normal'

Tags: python, tensorflow, ludwig

I'm trying to get [Uber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uber)'s Ludwig to run. I get an error about there being no attribute 'random_normal'. I can reproduce the error in Python with these commands.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000,1000]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random_normal'
>>> print(tf.__version__)
2.1.0
>>> print(sys.version)
3.7.5 (defaut, Oct 25 2019, 15:51:11)
[GCC 7.3.0]
```

How can I get past this error?

Comment: It was moved to `tf.random.normal` (as literally the first google result searching "tensorflow random_normal" shows...)

Comment: Ah, missed the underscore changing to period. Go ahead and create an answer if you like and I'll mark it as the best one.

Comment: @GPhilo this is the first google result

Comment: @Rainb Now, it may be. On Jan 28, it wasn't :)

Comment: Did it actually output "defaut"? Or is it a [transcription error](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/default#Noun)? I currently get "`Python 3.6.9 (default, Mar 10 2023, 16:46:00)`"

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It was moved to `tf.random.normal` (along with all the other `tf.random_*` functions)

Answer (score 7):

TensorFlow 2.0 comes with new [aliases](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/random/normal#aliases) for random_normal. Using `tf.random.normal` instead of `tf.random_normal` should execute successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method.
tf.reduce_sum(tf.compat.v1.random_normal([1000,1000]))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).